# Logarithmic grid disappearing from a certain x value

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am **making a plot in python using matplotlib.** The issue in which I have ran into is that once the x-Axis is scaled an order of magnitude more, the logarithmic grid disappears from the plot. The scaling is done through the function: `x_value_maker():` which generates a list that a function (`Phasenverschiebung_for_plot():`)iterates through.

Now **the catch is** that when the `x_value_maker():` generates a list up to 10000000 the logarithmic grid shows up just fine. However in order to put the data into prospective, I need a list that goes up to 100000000. When I change the range of the `x_value_maker():` to the necessary value the grid disappears.

So the question is how can I make the logarithmic grid stay  there and yet graph the desired function up to 100000000?

The code I am using is the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Raw data:
omega_1 = [622.0353454107791, 2043.480357454017, 4823.098705497194, 10103.361973944775, 21186.900855809567, 44151.94315355095, 86563.44397701316, 200075.46973651956, 451528.5457298466, 680657.4643267646, 1994735.4058409175, 4813736.759389496, 7052058.693219152] # in rad/sec
Phase_1_in_Rad_flipped = [1.548107046524, 1.569050997548, 1.565560339044, 1.567305668296, 1.541125729516, 1.40499004786, 1.23045712266, 0.97738438112, 0.577703982412, 0.380481776936, 0.1514945790736, 0.019198621772, -0.042411500823600005]

#Phasenverschiebung-Plot:
omega_value_list = []
def x_value_maker():
    # !!!THE LOG-GRID SHOWS UP WHEN THE in range statement range(1, 10000000, 100000) is as follows:  !!!
    for i in range(1, 100000000, 100000):
        omega_value_list.append(i)

x_value_maker()
#print(omega_value_list)
y_values_Phasenverschiebung = []

def Phasenverschiebung_for_plot():
    for elt in omega_value_list:
        new_elt = np.arctan(1/(elt*75*0.0000000045))
        y_values_Phasenverschiebung.append(new_elt)

Phasenverschiebung_for_plot()
#print(y_values_Phasenverschiebung)


plt.plot(omega_1, Phase_1_in_Rad_flipped, marker='o', label='Verbundene, gemessenen Punkte')
plt.plot(omega_value_list, y_values_Phasenverschiebung, label='Theoretische Erwartungen')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.ylabel('Phasenverschiebung [rad]')
plt.xlabel('Kreisfrequentz [rad/s]')
plt.grid(True, which="both")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

matplotlib tries to decide when there are too many ticks/gridlines, at which point it will change its behaviour to make the plot look cleaner. That is what you are seeing here: the number of ticks got too many, so it switched to only plotting ticks on every other integer power, and removed the minor ticks (the log-gridlines you want to keep).

Fortunately, we can control where the ticks go by setting the `major_locator` and `minor_locator` for the x-axis. Because its a log scale, we use the [`LogLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator) class to do this.

For example, we can increase the number of major ticks on the x-axis to get all the integer powers back by increasing `numticks` to 10 for the `major_locator`:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.LogLocator(base=10, numticks=10))
```

And to get the minor ticks back, we can increase the `numticks` to 100, and set `subs='all'` to get the ticks between integer powers, for the `minor_locator`:

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_minor_locator(plt.LogLocator(base=10, subs='all', numticks=100))
```

[image]

Comment: The result is definitely, what I was looking for, the explanation is great two. Only one thing still remains unclear to me and that is where in the code should I implement those two mentioned statements?

Comment: I put them right before your final line (`plt.show()`) and it worked